# is address of a variable considered a pointer to itself?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
   int num = 5; 
   
}
```

is &num consider a pointer to itself or is it only just an address?

I understand that pointer is a variable that stores address but is the address of an object/variable consider a pointer to itself?

Does a pointer have to be explicitly created using the * asterisk symbol (for e.g. int* intPtr = &num?

is the address of the variable itself (for e.g. &num) considered a pointer too?

Comment: Please focus on one question at a time. What does "pointer to itself" mean?

Comment: Address and pointer are synonymous as far as I can tell. You may be overcomplicating the issue

Comment: `num` is a variable of type `int`, initalised with value `5`.   `&num` (if your code was to compute it) is the address of `num`.    If we were to also define and initialise a pointer as `int intPtr = &num` then `intPtr` would a pointer to an `int` (i.e. an `int *`) and its value would be `&num`.    `intPtr` is not a pointer to itself, it is a pointer to `num`.  Similarly, `&num` is not a pointer to itself - it is the address of `num`.

Comment: @Peter Your comment is missing a `*` in the type of `intPtr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Yep.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Unfortunately, too long since I wrote it, so can't correct it.

Comment: `&num` is a pointer to the variable `num`, it's the address of the variable `num`

Answer (score 1):

If you take the address of `int num;` via `&num`, the type of that expression is `int*`, i.e., the same as if you were to declare `int* intPtr = &num;` and then use `intPtr`. So in that sense, it is 'the same'.